# How do you test e-mails sent to many recipients?

Tags: email, testing, sendgrid

I'm experimenting with using [SendGrid's SMTP API](http://docs.sendgrid.com/documentation/api/smtp-api/) to send an e-mail to many recipients. While it's easy to test this functionality against a handful of e-mails (I can just set up a few fake accounts with my e-mail host, then send to each of those and verify the message arrives in each inbox), it seems less easy to verify that everything works as expected for, say, a thousand recipients.

I'm wondering if there's any service that lets you bulk-create a ton of e-mail accounts (perhaps which expire from existence after a period of time?) and access all of their inboxes from a unified dashboard. For all I know that would be ridiculously expensive and impractical to implement; but I figured I'd ask anyway. In my particular case, that would be a very useful product indeed.

Comment: Are you trying to test that you can send out 1000 emails or that the emails you send are actually going to an inbox?

Comment: @Swift: The latter. And also measuring how long it takes.

Comment: You're better off signing up for accounts at the major mail providers (gmail, yahoo, hotmail, etc) and verifying that they go through for those since that will always be the bulk of your sending.  To measure the speed, you could set up push notifications from the Events API and calculate the time between the request and the delivery event (Docs here: http://docs.sendgrid.com/documentation/api/event-api/).  Not sure if I know a service that will just give you 1000 email accounts though, sorry!

Answer (score 2):

A better way to test this is to do the following:

- First, check your application logs to see if the delivery succeeded from your end.
- Next, determining the results of the actual delivery falls into the hands of SendGrid. SendGrid has a dashboard where you can see [email activity](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QgppoAkv3DM), and reports on bounces, blocks, spam reports, invalid emails, and unsubscribes.